# Alert dialogue, how to get both buttons to show up

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

why does the compiler show error for setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton in the code below.   If I use setButton there is no error but that only allows me to show one button on the alert dialog.   I want to have 2 buttons.   According to many tutorials, a two button alert dialog must be set with setPositiveButton, and setNegativeButton.   why are there compile erros for these?

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Confirm Edit");
        alert.setMessage("do you want to save edits?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // launches other activity if the user presses the OK button
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestScreen.class);
             MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edits saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edits Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, only you need to change it little bit. Create AlertDialog using Builder class.

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder ( MainActivity.this ); 
builder.setTitle ( "Confirm Edit" ); 
builder.setMessage("do you want to save edits?");

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // launches other activity if the user presses the OK button
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestScreen.class);
             MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edits saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edits Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });


// Now finally showing Alert Dialog.
AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
alert.show();
```